# I am using useEffect to hit api and return some response to display it.why this error is happening

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

*I am using useEffect to hit an api and display some data from the response.It works well in console but when i try to display the data in a component it throws an error.I am checking for the loading state though.I am showing the data after a i get a response then where does this null coming from*

**App.js file:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Details from './components/Details/Details';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import GlobalStyle from './globalStyles';

const API_KEY = 'Private';
// const URL = `https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=${API_KEY}&ipAddress=${ip}`;

function App() {
    const [ip, setIp] = useState('8.8.8.8');
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const res = await fetch(
                    `https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=${API_KEY}&ipAddress=${ip}`
                );
                const json = await res.json();
                setResponse(json);
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
        // return { response, error, isLoading };
    }, [ip]);
    return (
        <>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <Header getIp={(q) => setIp(q)} />

            <Details isLoading={isLoading} res={response} error={error} />
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Header.js file:**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FaArrowRight } from 'react-icons/fa';
import React from 'react';
import { Form, FormInput, Head, HeadLine, Button } from './Header.elements';
// import { useFetch } from '../../useFetch';

const Header = ({ getIp }) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const onChange = (q) => {
        setInput(q);
        getIp(q);
    };
    return (
        <>
            {/* styled components */}
            <Head>
                <HeadLine>IP Address Tracker</HeadLine>
                <Form
                    onSubmit={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        onChange(input);
                        setInput('');
                    }}
                >
                    <FormInput
                        value={input}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setInput(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        placeholder='Search for any IP address or Domain'
                    />
                    <Button type='submit'>
                        <FaArrowRight />
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </Head>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

**Details.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Location } from './Details.elements';

const Details = ({ res, error, isLoading }) => {
    console.log(res);
    return isLoading ? (
        <div>loading...</div>
    ) : (
        <>
            <Box>
                <Location>{res.location.city}</Location>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
};

export default Details;
```

**the error it shows:**
[image: chrome browser shows this error]

Comment: I'd guess that because React batches `setState` calls together, `isLoading` is never actually true

Comment: Initially `isLoading` is false, you initialize it to be false and you initialize response with null. Therefore on first render you get a null pointer exception. `useEffect` runs only after the element is committed into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because on the first render, Details component will receive isLoading=false and res=null, so it will try to render the box so it's throwing the error.

You can initialize isLoading as true.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```

Or render the Location if res has some value.

```
<Box>
   {res && <Location>{res.location.city}</Location>}
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to React documentation :
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

> By default, effects run after every completed render, but you can
> choose to fire them only when certain values have changed.

So your component is rendering at least once with isLoading as false before even the API call starts.

You have two choices here:

1. Set isLoading initial value to true
2. Add optional chaining res?.location.city

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-67755606-uuhqk